# Clear Data of Package for Single User

Tags: adb, shell, command-line, data

I am trying to clear the data for a few apps on a work profile without clearing the data on the main user account for my android phone.

What I'm trying for example is :

```
pm clear com.Microsoft.teams
```

Is there a way to clear just on the work profile and not my main account?

From my research, you can't seems to specify a user for this command unlike a few other commands: [pm documentation](https://android-doc.github.io/tools/help/shell.html#pm)

Comment: See the [latest documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#pm). Or `pm help | grep clear` which shows `clear [--user USER_ID] PACKAGE`

Comment: You can specify the userID for pm: `--user <USER_ID> `. You just need to find out which userID your work profile has.

Comment: Thanks the both of you. I was able to figure out the user id and clear it with that option.

Comment: @Kayracer You can write an answer yourself showing the commands you have used to get the user id and then how you deleted the data.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the commenters, I was able to figure it out.

I used Termux with root privileges, I typed the following:

To be super user

```
su
```

Then list the users

```
pm list users
```

The number in front of UserInfo{ is what you want

ie. in my case is 12

```
UserInfo{0::24} running
UserInfo{12:Work profile:35} running
```

Last enter the clear command

```
pm clear --user 12 <package to clear>
```